# Unable to connect to localhost database

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, localhost, drupal-8, acquia

This question has already been asked multiple times but none of the answers have helped me.

I am upgrading to Drupal 8 and to do so, I need to specify the login credentials for my Drupal 7 database.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it.

I can access the database perfectly fine to my SQL server is 100% running.
I have checked the credentials inside settings.php and it says the following:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'karma-living.dev',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

So I copied above but I still get the error message above (yellow box).

**See following image:**

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: which OS you are using ?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional

Comment: Instead of `localhost` try `127.0.0.1` as the host.

Comment: Already tried that and it didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: And you're positive with entered details; db host, db name, user name, port, etc? Because the details on the screenshot of Acquia Desktop and the ones entered in the migration form in Drupal don't seem to match.

Answer (score 1):

The Acquia Desktop says your database name is "karma_dev", but you've entered "karma-living.dev" as the name for Drupal, so there is an inconsistency.